# What is the Best Internet Provider in the Salt Lake Valley for hosting your future online business from home?

Tags: isp

This is for people familiar with the ISP scene in Salt Lake.  Also, UTOPIA is not available in my neighborhood yet.  I'm looking for comparisons between Comcast, Qwest, and especially other providers I'm not aware of.

While I will have online backup (of course!), I want to host some things from my own home at the start of my business.  Once money starts flowing in, I will move to a hosted provider, but in the meantime I would like a provider which provides fast (1+ mb/s at least) upload speeds (fast download a given), a static IP, and especially a reasonable price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The company I work for uses the basic [Comcast business class](http://business.comcast.com/internet/plans.aspx) Internet service which claims 12 Mbps down and 2 Mbps up for around $70 a month after taxes. We add an extra $10 a month for 5 public IP addresses (Not static, but have very long lease times. Static IPs cost extra) that are used for multiple VOIP lines from [RingCentral](http://blog.theg2.net/2009/08/farewell-vonage-hello-ringcentral.html). The service is very stable with only 48 hours of downtime over the last 5 or 6 years.

Having said that I still would not classify it as stable or fast enough for hosting anything that requires 24/7 uptime or a large amount of traffic. You never know when a residential cable is going to be cut or the power will go out. Plus a speed test shows that our uplink averages less than 1Mbps, which means you may need to go for the Premium or Deluxe plans that cost twice as much to make sure you have enough upload speed.

Your best alternative is to look at either a local co-location provider like [xmission.com](http://www.xmission.com/products/hosting/colocation/), which will let you install your own server in their SLC data center, or even better just buy a virtual server from someone like [Hosting.com](http://www.hosting.com/cloudhosting/vps/) or [Rackspace](http://www.rackspacecloud.com/cloud_hosting_products/servers/pricing). The virtual server will be fully managed and have a much better SLA than anything you could get from a residential or business grade ISP for less than $100 a month. You could always do shared hosting too (no root access, only FTP and hosting control panel), which can be found for as little as $10 a month depending on your needs.

Comment: Good analysis - I was thinking of xmission just hosting everything - the facts that they are local and have a good reputation are great.